# How can I connect a Yamaha PSS-A50 to rosegarden on Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: midi, rosegarden

I have a Yamaha PSS-A50 keyboard that I intend to use with rosegarden on Ubuntu Studio. The keyboard is seen by the computer; the response from lsusb is:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 011 Device 002: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 011 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 0499:1617 Yamaha Corp. PSR-E353 digital keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 013 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 012 Device 002: ID 1397:0509 BEHRINGER International GmbH UMC404HD 192k
Bus 012 Device 003: ID 0944:0120 KORG, Inc. KROME
Bus 012 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The keyboard is shown as a PSR-E353, which I presume is the underlying hardware.
As you can see from the list I also have a Korg keyboard that is seen, and more importantly works with rosegarden - at least partly. Rosegarden responds to Midi information from the Korg and the transport window shows note on & velocity information for it, but nothing for the Yamaha. I managed to create an .rgd file for the Krome from a .ins file, do I need to do the same for the Yamaha? Is an .rgd/.ins file even available for the Yamaha or will I have to make one myself?